# assimp-vc140-mt.dll ASSIMP was not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, linker, assimp

I have downloaded the Assimp project from http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_downloads.html

[Assimp release image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBc1x.png)

[assimp zip image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEAoj.png)

And I've also downloaded the cmake x86 version from this link: https://cmake.org/download/

[cmake x86 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II81s.png)

I have extracted both, and made a build folder next to the assimp's folder.
After that I have opened a command promt, changed the directory to the mentioned build folder. I gave the `cmake.exe`'s path to the command promt and the assimp folder's path as the first parameter. After that I had the visual studio solution in the build folder.
I have made an assimp folder in my openGL project. In this assimp folder I've created a `lib` folder and I put everything from the build/code/debug folder into it, namely:

```
assimp-vc140-mt.dll
assimp-vc140-mt.exp
assimp-vc140-mt.ilk
assimp-vc140-mt.lib
assimp-vc140-mt.pdb
```

After that I copied the include folder from the downloaded assimp folder next to the previously mentioned `lib` folder.
So now I have all the libs and includes inside my openGl project
I have set the additional include directories, the additional libraries and the additional dependencies in the visual studio for my openGl project

In my `main.cpp` I have included these headers:

```
include "assimp/Importer.hpp"
include "assimp/scene.h"
include "assimp/postprocess.h"
```

I can build my project and run it.
But when I run it after the console appears I immediately get this error:

```
assimp-vc140-mt.dll was not found
```

I don't know what could be the source of the error, do you have any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you put `assimp-vc140-mt.dll` in the same folder as your executable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget dependant DLLs which are not system DLLs are loaded from application directory and from current directory - to me it sounds like you haven't put assimp-vc140-mt.dll in either of those.

Comment: Okay that helped, thank you.
Could you tell my why I have to put this dll into the exe 's directory but I don't have to do the same with the glew and soil and other libraries? I'm pretty new in c++ so sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: glew may be linked dynamically from the code from an appropriate directory. For implicit linking, DLLs follow [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx)

Either that, or you're linking "other libraries" statically, as in their code ends up being embedded in resulting executable directly.