# assimp-vc140-mt.dll was not found

Tags: c++, dll, runtime-error, visual-studio-2019, assimp

[assimp-vc140-mt.dll ASSIMP was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253826/assimp-vc140-mt-dll-assimp-was-not-found)
is really the same question but the answers dont solve the problem for me.

I have placed the DLL in the same folder as the EXE and the solution but I am still getting the same run time error where the DLL is missing.

[picture of my EXE folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmEpw.png)

[picture of SLN folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heXdu.png)

That is where a think the DLL should be in accordions to the previous question. But when i run the compiler [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ9FW.png)

Thank you

Comment: Ought to be somewhat obvious from the error message, 142 is not 140.  https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/3004

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont seam to understand. I am using visual Studio 2019 and the DLL is named 142. Is'nt that the right name? In that case what should I do to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Your program is looking for the debug dll (that's what the last character in the stem is - 'd'). You currently only have the release dll.

Compile a debug version of the assimp library.

Example process to do so:

Clone the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/assimp/assimp.git
```

Create `build` directory inside repository directory:

```
cd assimp
mkdir build
cd build
```

Build the program in Debug mode

```
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Debug
```

Once you have done that you should have `assimp-vc142-mtd.dll` in `assimp/build/bin/Debug`, copy that to the folder with the executable.

Comment: Thanks so much. This solved the error message. It may be stupid to ask but is there any reason to use one over the other. (debug DLL or Release DLL) I mean if I build my lib to handle it of course.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of all the changes Debug has to Release. I know Release optimises a lot of the code (this might be changing order of operations, omitting unused variables, removing C asserts, etc). Debug also outputs databases and symbols (not too sure what they are either), so that you can set a breakpoints.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.